# Kotlin: Keeping multiple profiles inside @ActiveProfiles annotation?

Tags: spring, kotlin

I know that in java, multiple active profiles can be kept using -

```
@ActiveProfiles({"profile1", "profile2"})
```

But I need a similar construct for kotlin. Above doesnt work with kotlin and gives error saying - `Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)`. I also tried `@ActiveProfiles(profile = arrayOf("profile1", "profile2"))` and also tried `@Profile("profile1 & profile2")`. Nothing seems to work. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the source of `@ActiveProfiles` you'll see the following constructor:

```
/**
 * Alias for {@link #profiles}.
 * <p>This attribute may <strong>not</strong> be used in conjunction with
 * {@link #profiles}, but it may be used <em>instead</em> of {@link #profiles}.
 */
@AliasFor("profiles")
String[] value() default {};
```

This means its expecting an array of strings for 'profiles' -> just create an array as you normally do it in Kotlin and pass it to the constructor like that:

```
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = arrayOf("profile1", "profile1"))
```

Answer (score 1):

The shortest form would be:

```
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = ["profile1", "profile2"])
```